# Calculate VaR using method of historical simulation

Tags: options, finance, historical-data, value-at-risk

A bank invests € $1.000.000$ in a hedge fund. The last 500 daily returns can be taken from a database. The worst 20 returns are

-4.58   -2.95   -2.95   -2.93   -2.17   -2.08   -2.06   -1.98   -1.94   -1.89   -1.83   -1.75   -1.73   -1.56   -1.54   -1.52   -1.45   -1.37   -1.17   -0.89

I want to determine the ten-day 99%-VaR using historical simulation.

According to my course material I need to determine the 5-highest loss and multiply it by $\sqrt {10}$.

Do I even need the € $1.000.000$ from the task?

Comment: These seem to be % returns? To get the VaR as € amount, you multiply the 5th worst return 2.17% by €1mil (and also 10-day horizon).

Comment: Your 5th highest loss (scaled by $\sqrt{10}$) will give you the percentage loss at the 99th percentile over a 10-day horizon. If you want to convert this to a "Eur value", you need to multiply by the 1 million eur notional.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Thanks!